# Pass the name of a button to a textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8

I need a little help here. I have 40 buttons on a Master-Details MVVM sketch. As you know, I tap a button from MainPage and it displays data on DetailsPage.
What I need to do is to tap on any button (1,2,3...40) and it to send its name (Semana 1, 2,...,40) as the header of the Details Page.
I can achieve this by naming each button

```XAML
<StackPanel x:Name="Semanas1a5">
    <Button x:Name="bs1" Content="Semana 1" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <Button x:Name="bs2" Content="Semana 2" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    <Button x:Name="bs3" Content="Semana 3" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
    <Button x:Name="bs4" Content="Semana 4" Click="Button_Click_4"/>
    <Button x:Name="bs5" Content="Semana 5" Click="Button_Click_5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Then passing its name as parameter within the navigation command.

```C#
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DataBoundApp1;component/MainPage.xaml?hdr=" + bs1.Content, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

However I think there must be a wiser way of doing it by INotifyPropertyChanged or anything else instead of writing a name for each one of the 40.
Anyone has a suggestion?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding a `Click` event for each button, why not have them all share the same event?

```
<StackPanel Button.Click="OnButtonClick">
      <Button Content="Semana 1"/>
      <Button Content="Semana 2"/>
      <Button Content="Semana 3"/>
      <Button Content="Semana 4"/>
      <Button Content="Semana 5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Then, you can use the `RoutedEventArgs` to receive the `OriginalSource`, from which you can get the `Content` property!

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = e.OriginalSource as Button;
    if (clickedButton != null)
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DataBoundApp1;component/MainPage.xaml?hdr=" + clickedButton.Content, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: or you could try this way too
Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

Comment: <StackPanel Button.Click="OnButtonClick"> says I cannot use click command on stackpanel because it does not inherits from button base

Comment: @GeovanniOrtega: can you show me the error because that should work. Are you doing it in the code behind?